# Problema ao aplicar Pop up Jquery em plataforma de e-commerce

Tags: jquery

Estou trabalhando com uma plataforma de e-commerce, no caso a loja integrada. Tenho acesso a incluir html para personalizar, porém o código é ativado para todas as páginas do site, existe algo que eu possa fazer para que fique apenas na home sob as atuais condições que estou?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);  
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    $('#dialog2').css('top',  winH/2-$('#dialog2').height()/2);
    $('#dialog2').css('left', winW/2-$('#dialog2').width()/2);

    $('#dialog2').fadeIn(2000); 

  $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#mask').hide();
    $('.window').hide();
  });   

  $('#mask').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
  });     

});
```

Comment: Use o botão [edit] para poder adicionar mais informações a ela.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt, poderia colocar um print mostrando o problema ? já deu para entender que você está sofrendo um efeito em cascata por carregar esse script em todas as paginas, mas queria saber exatamente como isso ocorre e qual plataforma é

Comment: Já consegui resolver o problema, como encerro esta pergunta para não prender a atenção da galera que vem ajudar?

Comment: Responda a pergunta com a solução para o problema. Você não vai conseguir marcar como resposta por causa da reputação (eu acho).

Answer (score -1):

Bom o problema foi resolvido sem a necessidade de alterar algo, consegui colocar esse pop up apenas na home através da plataforma.

Obrigado

Comment: Pode explicar como fez isso? A mesma solução que encontrou pode ajudar e ser útil para outros usuários.